# How to efficiently sum the upper left coner of a matrix using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

The naive python way is:

```
 sum(grid[x,y] for x in xrange(a) for y in xrange(a-x))
```

I am looking for a speed-up given that `grid` is a 2d square matrix in numpy. `tril` doesn't work since it works on the upper right coner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rotate the matrix first:

```
np.sum(np.tril(np.rot90(grid)))
```

Note that `rot90` makes a view, rather than a copy of the data. Here are a couple timing tests to show the relative speeds of the two versions for two array sizes:

```
In [1]: grid = np.random.rand(10000,10000)

In [2]: a = grid.shape[0]

In [3]: %time sum1 = np.sum(grid[x,y] for x in xrange(a) for y in xrange(a-x))
CPU times: user 18.68 s, sys: 0.04 s, total: 18.72 s
Wall time: 18.60 s

In [4]: %time sum2 = np.sum(np.tril(np.rot90(grid)))
CPU times: user 1.73 s, sys: 0.55 s, total: 2.27 s
Wall time: 2.28 s
```

The second version was over 8 times faster. Just to confirm that the versions are equivalent:

```
In [5]: np.allclose(sum1, sum2)
Out[5]: True
```

And for a smaller array:

```
In [6]: grid = np.random.rand(100,100)

In [7]: a = grid.shape[0]

In [8]: %timeit sum1 = np.sum(grid[x,y] for x in xrange(a) for y in xrange(a-x))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit sum2 = np.sum(np.tril(np.rot90(grid)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.4 us per loop
```

For this smaller array, the second version was over 20 times faster.

Comment: Does this create a copy or a view of the original matrix? It looks like it creates a new copy, which could be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Good question. It creates a view (at least it did when I tested it). In the version of numpy I used (1.7.1), the doc string doesn't state whether a copy or view is returned.

Comment: It's a view. The same result can be obtained with a more explicit view: `np.sum(np.tril(x[::-1, ::-1].T))`.

Comment: @larsmans Thanks, I came to the same conclusion you did since links to the source are provided in the docs. Do you think it's explicitly worth mentioning in the docs that a view is created, not a copy?

Comment: @Hooked: that's certainly useful. NumPy docs could be much more explicit in this regard.

Comment: @larsmans I like your suggestion of using slices but your version doesn't work for me. But it does work with `np.sum(np.tril(x[::-1,:]))` or even just `np.sum(np.tril(x[::-1]))`.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more verbose version of @bogatron's answer that may explain what is going on underneath:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

mask = (np.tri(*A.shape,dtype=bool).T)[:,::-1]

print A[mask].sum()
```

In this case the mask looks like:

```
[[ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True False False False]
 [ True False False False False]]
```

which is the upper corner of the matrix.